# Markov chains and an integral equation

Tags: markov-chains, integral-equations

I'm struggling with solving the following problem numerically:

> Given $\sigma>0, X_0 \in (0,1)$ and a markov chain defined by $X_{i+1}=X_{i}+N(0,\sigma^2)  \ \forall i \in \mathbb{Z^{0+}}$. What is the probability that $min(\{i : X_i < 0\}) < min(\{i : X_i > 1\})$?
> In other words, what is the probability this markov chains hits $0$  before it hits $1$?

I've managed to reduce the problem to solving the following integral equation:

Define $E = min(\{i : X_i < 0\}) < min(\{i : X_i > 1\})\\$
Write $$f(x) = \mathbb{P}(E | X_0 = x) $$ then we can say that $$f(x) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(E|X_0=x,X_1=y)P(X_1=y) dy \\ = \int_{-\infty}^{0}1  \times P(X_1=y) dy + \int_{0}^{1} f(y)  \times P(X_1=y) dy + \int_{1}^{\infty}0  \times P(X_1=y) dy \\ = \Phi(\frac{-x}{\sigma}) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{0}^{1} f(y)\exp{(-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2\sigma^2})} dy$$

So we have a fredholm equation of the second kind.

Unfortunately, I've been trying to get mathematica to solve this numerically (for a given $\sigma$) but I cannot yield any reasonable numerical solutions. (I am expecting a decreasing function, with $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$)

So I have three questions:

1. Is my logic up to the point of the integral equation correct?
2. Are there any tricks I'm missing that would simplify this equation?
3. How can I solve this numerically?

Comment: What is $\Phi$?

Comment: CDF of N(0,1) distribution

Comment: The equation looks right. A question I might ask is whether you can just use fixed point iteration, which comes down to whether $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}} \right )^2 \, dx \, dy$ is less than $1$ or not. In the case $\sigma=1$ it is, which means that you can just do fixed point iteration with $f_0=1-x$ by quadrature. Thus for instance $f_1(x)=\Phi(-x) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^1 (1-y) \exp \left ( -\frac{(y-x)^2}{2} \right ) \, dy$. Approximate that on some mesh by quadrature and continue.

Comment: Unfortunately if the variance is too small this approach doesn't work anymore. In that case you would just want to set up the integral by quadrature and use the definition of your quadrature rule to obtain a linear system for $f$ at the grid points. You can then interpolate $f$ between grid points in some way (e.g. linear interpolation) if you wish.

Comment: Thanks, yes that integral you describe is less than 1 unless I'm mistaken. Inner function is a PDF over a fraction of the support, so the first integral is < 1 everywhere on [0,1], so the second integral should be fine too. EDIT: Although on second thought, the squaring might cause trouble...

Comment: The squaring causes trouble at small variance yes.

Comment: But yeah, a perfectly good way to solve $f(x)=F(x)+\int_0^1 k(x,y) f(y) \, dy$ is to set up a linear system with $f_i=F(ih)+\frac{1}{n} \left ( k(ih,0) f_0/2 + k(ih,1) f_n/2 + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} k(ih,jh) f_j \right )$, which is just that integral equation written in quadrature with the trapezoidal rule, where $h=1/n$. In this context you can just replace $f_0=1,f_n=0$ and then go from there.

Comment: An alternate way to do it is to build a finite state Markov chain approximation by assembling a Markov chain with states, say, $(-\infty,0),[0,1/n),\dots,[(n-1)/n,1),[1,\infty)$ and then taking the transition probability $p_{ij}$ to be the exact probability to go from the center of the $i$th interval to anywhere in the $j$th interval. In this problem this is not so painful to do because you can evaluate the probabilities exactly in terms of $\Phi$.

Comment: Yes, so for the finite case, where we simply flip a coin and move to either (m+1)/n or (m-1)/n when starting from m/n then surprisingly the result is that P(hit zero first) is m/n. This one is fairly easy to solve, and I suspect is the approximate solution in the small-sigma case. I suppose I'm most curious about the intermediate cases, where the chance you blow through the 0 or 1 barrier is non-trivial. Thanks for all your help! I'm going to try the quadrature approach. I've not really dealt with integral eqns much before. (I managed to get a 3rd in my 4-th year linear operators class!)

Comment: Yes, you'll get $m/n$ in the $\sigma \to 0$ limit.

Answer (score 1):

One numerical approach goes like this. I like this kind of method because it is giving an exact solution to a related finite dimensional problem.

Given an integer $n \geq 1$, consider a finite state Markov chain on $n+2$ states, which we identify with $(-\infty,0),[0,1/n),[1/n,2/n),\dots,[(n-1)/n,1),[1,\infty)$. We'll zero index the states. We treat state $0$ (identified with $(-\infty,0)$) and state $n+1$ (identified with $[1,\infty)$) as absorbing states.

Starting from one of the other states $i$, define the probability to go from $i$ to $j$ to be the exact probability that the original process would go from the center of the $i$th interval to anywhere in the $j$th interval.

Then the transition probabilities are given as

\begin{align}
p_{i,j} & =F \left ( \frac{j}{n} - \frac{2i-1}{2n}  \right ) - F \left ( \frac{j-1}{n} - \frac{2i-1}{2n} \right ) \quad i,j=1,2,\dots,n \\
p_{i,0} & = F \left ( -\frac{2i-1}{2n} \right ) \quad i=1,2,\dots,n \\
p_{i,n+1} & = 1-F \left ( 1-\frac{2i-1}{2n} \right ) \quad i=1,2,\dots,n
\end{align}

where $F(x)=\Phi(x/\sigma)$.

Finally, consider $u_i$ to be the probability to hit state $0$ before state $n+1$ starting from state $i$, and assemble the $p_{i,j}$ into a $(n+2) \times (n+2)$ matrix $P$. Then the desired system of equations reads

\begin{align}
(Pu)_i - u_i & = 0 \quad i=1,2,\dots,n \\
u_0 & = 1 \\
u_{n+1} & = 0.
\end{align}

You can then construct an approximate solution to the original problem by e.g. linear interpolation.

Interestingly, these numerics show a discontinuity at the boundaries, which actually makes sense: no matter how close you get to the boundary, there is a chance, however small, that you will instantly jump past the *other* boundary in the very next step. This goes to zero as $\sigma \to 0$ of course, and is already very small as soon as $\sigma$ is say $1/3$, but still, it is there as long as $\sigma>0$.